# is it possible to use ofstream to read a file by having mode as ios::in

Tags: c++

I tried running below code

```
/* filename : file.cpp */
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ofstream file;
   string s;
   file.open("file1.txt",ios::in);
   if(file.is_open())
   {
     while(getline(file,s))
     {
       cout<<s<<endl;
     }
     file.close();
   }
   else
   {
      cout<<"file open failed";
   }
}
```

But it gave below compilation error

```
file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file.cpp:14:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::ofstream&, std::__cxx11::string&)’
  while(getline(file,s))
                      ^
```

When `ios::in` is allowed as a `mode` in `ofstream::open()` why cant i read from a file using `ofstream`. what could be the issue here?

Comment: Of course it is. You didn't write a `main()` function... Real answer: Show _all_ the code and _quote_ the errors. But the answer is probably just 'that's how enums work' and 'just don't do that'.

Comment: Well, you certainly can't pass an `std::ofstream&` as the first arg to [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) takes `std::istream&`, not `std::ostream&`.

Comment: @underscore_d updated the code and the error

Comment: @Jarod42 in this case instead of getline() what else i can use here ?

Comment: You might probably then have to play with base class interface, as `rdbuf` and use directly `std::basic_streambuf`... but why not use `std::ifstream` at the first place?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you're trying to use `std::ofstream` here?

Comment: @G.M. not for any specific purpose.wanted to check whether this will work or not